# Permutations in python 2.5.2

Tags: python, list, permutation

I have a list of numbers for input, e.g.

```
671.00   
1,636.00
436.00
9,224.00
```

and I want to generate all possible sums with a way to id it for output, e.g.:

```
671.00 + 1,636.00 = 2,307.00
671.00 + 436.00 = 1,107.00
671.00 + 9,224.00 = 9,224.00
671.00 + 1,636.00 + 436.00 = 2,743.00
...
```

and I would like to do it in Python
My current constrains are:
a) I'm just learning python now (that's part of the idea)
b) I will have to use Python 2.5.2 (no intertools)

I think I have found a piece of code that may help:

```
def all_perms(str):
    if len(str) <=1:
        yield str
    else:
        for perm in all_perms(str[1:]):
            for i in range(len(perm)+1):
                #nb str[0:1] works in both string and list contexts
                yield perm[:i] + str[0:1] + perm[i:]
```

( from [these guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python) )

But I'm not sure how to use it in my propose.
Could someone trow some tips and pieces of code of help?

cheers,

f.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations has equivalent code to `itertools.permutations`

Comment: Are you sure you want `636 + 1636` and `1636 + 636` as distinct elements?

Comment: I think this is more *combinations* than *permutations*.

Comment: I think too. Before going into Python's stuff, could you write the algorithm you want to use to do the job ? There are several way to get the result you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Permutations* are about taking an ordered set of things and moving these things around (i.e. changing order). Your question is about *combinations* of things from your list.

Now, an easy way of enumerating combinations is by mapping entries from your list to bits in a number. For example, lets assume that if bit #0 is set (i.e. 1), then number `lst[0]` participates in the combination, if bit #1 is set, then `lst[1]` participates in the combination, etc. This way, numbers in range `0 <= n < 2**(len(lst))` identify all possible combinations of `lst` members, including an empty one (`n = 0`) and the whole `lst` (`n = 2**(len(lst)) - 1`).

You need only combinations of 2 items or more, i.e. only those combination IDs that have at least two nonzero bits in their binary representation. Here is how to identify these:

```
def HasAtLeastTwoBitsSet(x) :
    return (x & (x-1)) != 0

# Testing:
>>> [x for x in range(33) if HasAtLeastTwoBitsSet(x)]
[3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
```

Next step is to extract a combination of list members identified by a combination id. This is easy, thanks to the power of list comprehensions:

```
def GetSublistByCombination(lst, combination_id) :
    res = [x for (i,x) in enumerate(lst) if combination_id & (1 << i)]
    return res

# Testing:
>>> GetSublistByCombination([0,1,2,3], 1)
[0]
>>> GetSublistByCombination([0,1,2,3], 3)
[0, 1]
>>> GetSublistByCombination([0,1,2,3], 12)
[2, 3]
>>> GetSublistByCombination([0,1,2,3], 15)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Now let's make a generator that produces all sums, together with their string representations:

```
def IterAllSums(lst) :
    combinations = [i for i in range(1 << len(lst)) if HasAtLeastTwoBitsSet(i)]
    for comb in combinations :
        sublist = GetSublistByCombination(lst, comb)
        sum_str = '+'.join(map(str, sublist))
        sum_val = sum(sublist)
        yield (sum_str, sum_val)
```

And, finally, let's use it:

```
>>> for sum_str, sum_val in IterAllSums([1,2,3,4]) : print sum_str, sum_val

1+2 3
1+3 4
2+3 5
1+2+3 6
1+4 5
2+4 6
1+2+4 7
3+4 7
1+3+4 8
2+3+4 9
1+2+3+4 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below generates all "subsets" of a given list (except the empty set), i.e. it returns a list of lists.

```
def all_sums(l): #assumes that l is non-empty
    if len(l)==1:
        return ([[l[0]]])
    if len(l)==0:
        return []
    result = []
    for i in range(0,len(l)):
        result.append([l[i]])
        for p in all_sums(l[i+1:]):
            result.append([l[i]]+p)
    return result
```

Now you could just write a short function `doit` for output also:

```
def doit(l):
    mylist = all_sums(l)
    print mylist
    for i in mylist:
        print str(i) + " = " + str(sum(i))

doit([1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 0):

With itertools (Python >=2.6) would be:

```
from itertools import *
a=[1,2,3,4]
sumVal=[tuple(imap(sum,combinations(a,i))) for i in range(2,len(a)+1)]
```